# How to speed up by Compile?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, compile

I need to `NDSolve` a system many times by scanning some of its parameters and do some matrix calculation with the (discretized) solutions. The example is the following code. *The system `eqs` looks formidable, but the concrete form doesn't matter.*

Because the computation is quite heavy (I actually need much denser meshes for scanning the parameters, I mean the lists I defined in the middle), I was wondering if any further speed improvement possible. Probably by properly Compile the program? I've heard of great gain by compile to C or machine code. But I somehow got lost in the related documentation. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Note that the `NDSolve` part sometimes takes less or comparable time than the matrix calculations followed, depending on how dense we scan particular parameters.

```
eqs = {I Derivative[1][B1][t] == 
    Abs[B1[t]]^2 (m B1[t] + B3[t] (x - I y + Cos[t] - I Sin[t])) + 
     Abs[B2[t]]^2 (m B1[t] + 
        B3[t] (x - I y + Cos[t] - I Sin[t])) + (B1[t] Conjugate[
          B3[t]] + B2[t] Conjugate[B4[t]]) (-m B3[t] + 
        B1[t] (x + I y + Cos[t] + I Sin[t])), 
   I Derivative[1][B2][t] == 
    Abs[B1[t]]^2 (m B2[t] + B4[t] (x - I y + Cos[t] - I Sin[t])) + 
     Abs[B2[t]]^2 (m B2[t] + 
        B4[t] (x - I y + Cos[t] - I Sin[t])) + (B1[t] Conjugate[
          B3[t]] + B2[t] Conjugate[B4[t]]) (-m B4[t] + 
        B2[t] (x + I y + Cos[t] + I Sin[t])), 
   I Derivative[1][B3][t] == 
    B1[t] (m (B3[t] Conjugate[B1[t]] + 
           B4[t] Conjugate[B2[t]]) + (Abs[B3[t]]^2 + 
           Abs[B4[t]]^2) (x + I y + Cos[t] + I Sin[t])) + 
     B3[t] (-m (Abs[B3[t]]^2 + 
           Abs[B4[t]]^2) + (B3[t] Conjugate[B1[t]] + 
           B4[t] Conjugate[B2[t]]) (x + Cos[t] - I (y + Sin[t]))), 
   I Derivative[1][B4][t] == 
    B2[t] (m (B3[t] Conjugate[B1[t]] + 
           B4[t] Conjugate[B2[t]]) + (Abs[B3[t]]^2 + 
           Abs[B4[t]]^2) (x + I y + Cos[t] + I Sin[t])) + 
     B4[t] (-m (Abs[B3[t]]^2 + 
           Abs[B4[t]]^2) + (B3[t] Conjugate[B1[t]] + 
           B4[t] Conjugate[B2[t]]) (x + Cos[t] - I (y + Sin[t])))};
ic = {B1[-tmax] == 1, B2[-tmax] == 0, B3[-tmax] == 0, B4[-tmax] == 1};
var = {B1, B2, B3, B4};

tmax = 25; m = 0.4;
tlist = Table[i, {i, 10, 30, 5}];
ttmax = tmax; ttmesh = ttmax/10; ttlist = Table[tt, {tt, -ttmax, ttmax, ttmesh}];
rmax = 2.0; rmesh = 0.1; rlist = Table[r, {r, -rmax, rmax, rmesh}];
omax = 1.0; omesh = omax/60; olist = Table[o, {o, -omax, omax, omesh}];
smat = Table[Exp[-(t1 - myt)^2/5 + I o t1], {o, olist}, {myt, tlist}, {t1, ttlist}];
G0 = {{x^2, y}, {-y, x y}};

data = ParallelTable[
   Module[{sol = Last[#] & /@ (First@NDSolve[{eqs, ic}, var, {t, -tmax, tmax}]), Bsol},
    Bsol = Table[Map[#@t1 &, sol, {1}], {t1, ttlist}]; 
    Map[#.G0.ConjugateTranspose[#] &@(ttmesh Partition[#1.Bsol, 2]) &, smat, {2}]], {x, rlist}, {y, rlist}];
```

Comment: 1. Given the system isn't that large, I doubt if `Compile` will help. 2. Why not `ParametricNDSolve`?

Comment: @xzczd 1. I actually need much denser mesh for scanning the parameters, I mean the lists I defined. 2. Thanks for point that out. Maybe that helps. But the `NDSolve` part actually can take much less time than the matrix calculations followed, depending on how dense we scan particular parameters. So I was wondering if any Compile can give some overall improvement.

Comment: I presume you are already aware of [this list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tst = 
   Block[{x = rlist[[1]], y = rlist[[1]]}, 
    Module[{sol = (Last[#1] &) /@ First[NDSolve[{eqs, ic}, var, {t, -tmax, tmax}]], 
      Bsol}, Bsol = Table[Map[#1[t1] &, sol, {1}], {t1, ttlist}]; 
     Map[(#1 . G0 . ConjugateTranspose[#1] &)[ttmesh Partition[#1 . Bsol, 2]] &, 
      smat, {2}]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0249631, Null} *)

pnd = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqs, ic}, 
   ArrayReshape[Outer[#2[#] &, ttlist, var], {Length@ttlist, 2, 2}], {t, -tmax, 
    tmax}, {x, y}];

cmap = With[{ttmesh = ttmesh, G0 = G0, smat = smat}, 
   Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {Bsol, _Complex, 3}(*,{smat,_Complex,3}*)}, 
    With[{mat = ttmesh smat . Bsol}, 
     Module[{m, n}, {m, n} = Dimensions[mat][[;; 2]]; 
      Table[(mat[[i, j]] . G0 . ConjugateTranspose[mat[[i, j]]]), {i, m}, {j, n}]]], 
    CompilationTarget -> C]];

tst3 = Block[{x = rlist[[1]], y = rlist[[1]]}, 
    With[{Bsol = pnd[x, y]}, cmap[x, y, Bsol(*,smat*)]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0196469, Null} *)

tst3 - tst // Abs // Max
(* 2.8917*10^-14 *)
```

If you don't have a C compiler installed, take the  `CompilationTarget -> C` away. The corresponding timing will be a bit slower, of course.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This indeed speeds it up. But when I use it inside `ParallelTable` or `Table` as the end of my original post, it's only 1/3 or 1/2 the original time cost, surprisingly far worse than the test you showed. Is it something wrong or inefficient in such a usage?

Comment: @xiaohuamao Oh `RepeatedTiming` is missleading in this case, because `ParametricNDSolveValue` caches the previous results… Timing in answer revised.

Comment: @xiaohuamao BTW, it's worth pointing out differential equation solving is much more time-consuming than subsequent matrix calculation, at least for this toy example. If in real cases the matrix calculation is the bottleneck, you may consider compiling the code further. (Something like `Compile[…, Table[cmap[…], …]`. )

Comment: Thanks. Most of the calculation is what I show here -- just put it inside `Table` or `ParallelTable` finally. But instead of that, will it be further beneficial to use the option `RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, Parallelization -> True` and make `cmap` only take `[x,y]` as the argument? I tried but couldn't figure out how to deal with the input from `pnd`.

Comment: @xiaohuamao I doubt if `RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, Parallelization -> True` will help, because you've already used `ParallelTable`. (Notice `Compile[…, CompilationTarget -> C]` won't generate parallelized C code, parallelization happens only in _Mathematica_ kernel. ) Anyway you can try it out. You don't need any special treatment for the input from `pnd`, just observe the behavior of the following sample: `cf = Compile[{{a, _Real, 2}}, a[[1, 2]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]; cf[{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}]`

Comment: Sorry, I actually stupidly got stuck in reducing `With[{Bsol = pnd[x, y]}, cmap[x, y, Bsol]]` directly into the definition of `cmap`, i.e., getting something like `cmap[x, y]`. Do we need to `Table` the whole `pnd` data to be used before making `cmap`?

Comment: @xiao If I've understood what you mean correctly, yes. First generate a list of `Bsol` i.e. `Bsollist=(*Parallel*)Table[pnd[x,y],{x,rlist},{y,rlist}]`, then something like `cmaplistable=
  With[{ttmesh=ttmesh,G0=G0},Compile[{{x,_Real},{y,_Real},{Bsol, _Complex,3}, {smat, _Complex, 3}},With[{mat = ttmesh smat.Bsol}, Module[{m, n}, {m,n} = Dimensions[mat][[;; 2]];Table[(mat[[i, j]].G0.ConjugateTranspose[mat[[i,j]]]), {i, m}, {j,n}]]],CompilationTarget->C,RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]];
data5=cmaplistable[#\[Transpose],#,Bsollist,smat] &@ConstantArray[rlist, Length@rlist]; // AbsoluteTiming`